# Table with overlapping areas of 2 maps?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a base map with various land use. to this I have to superimpose a shape with the polylines that delimit the areas.

How can I get the surfaces of each ground use that fall within each polyline?

Comment: Is the land use data in vector or raster format?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Polygon  You could use Intersect  from menu Vector -> GeoProcessing Tools -> Intersect

the choode the layer you want to intersect .. this tool create a new vector with the result  .

You can try for polylines if produce the correct result

Answer (score 1):

Spero che le immagini ti aiuteranno a trovare gli strumenti corretti anche se la spiegazione e la mia versione di QGIS sono in inglese. (tradotto dall'inglese all'italiano usando Google Traduttore)

---

First, convert polylines to polygons using the `Lines to polygons` tool.

[image]

Next, extract the land use data that falls within each polygon:

- If land use data is a **raster** layer, use `Clip raster by mask layer` tool

[image]

- If land use data is a **vector** layer, use `Clip` tool

[image]

Note: vector attributes (like area or perimeter) are not updated by the Clip tool. You must manually update them.